# .htaccess - is rewriting one part of the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [nc]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . url_handle.php
```

What I am trying to do is have a www rewrite rule so that urls without www. redirect to the same url with www. prefix. I am also using clean URL's, so any unknown URL is sent to url_handle.php for processing.

The problem is that if I have a url like "http://mysite.com/part_1/part_2/part_3", the URL is redirected and then reads "http://www.mysite.com/url_handle.php/part_2/part_3", ommitting the "part_1" and replacing it with "url_handle.php".

Comment: Do you have more rules after that or other htaccess files around? It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to redirect non-www sites to www use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

It means, if the url is not "www.mysite.com" and if not blank redirect to "www.mysite.com"

---

Secondly, to redirect unknown sites to a specific page use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/url_handle.php [R=301,L]
```

The last row will save you :)

Comment: I need to keep my URL structure, this for some reason changed all URL's to url_handle.php